# Network Manager AP Configuration

Tags: debian, networkmanager, armbian

I would need to configure my Single board computer as an AP, and I managed to do it before and it was working flawlessly (the AP is isolated and not connected to the WAN).

Then today, I needed to connect it online to install some packages.
As I have all my connections config in different .nmconnection files, I have modified my AP config file with autoconnect =false and my client mode connection as autoconnect=true, then I rebooted.
After reboot, the device has never shown up in my router list. The connection file was working few months ago when I set it up.

then, I decided to accept my fate, and switch back to the original config (APconnection file with autoconnect, client connection file without autoconnect)
and then, at the reboot, the AP doesn't show up now.

Can someone help me to figure out what could have happened or help me to diagnose this?

below my AP conenction file as well as my networkmanager.conf

```
[connection]
id=AP
uuid=1cfa65ae-cd8b-4d19-8d18-5ca935fc9d27
type=wifi
interface-name=wlan0
permissions=
autoconnect=true

[wifi]
band=bg
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=ap
ssid=PROJECTprototype

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=password

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

[proxy]
```

and networkmanager.conf

```
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
rc-manager=file
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is likely that the configuration file wasn't a problem.
I have loaded back a back up and tested the configuration from a back-up. Everything works fine.

Likely the problem was not coming from here.